# Azure Event Hub subscriber in .NET Core

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-eventhub

Azure Event Hub subscriber in .NET Core not automatically accruing storage hub lease while redeploying in to app service. Any help will be highly appreciated.
`var storageClientResult = new BlobContainerClient(StorageHubConnection, hubname); Task.Run(async () => await ProcessClients(consumerGroup, storageClientResult, hubname)).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is the code inside *ProcessClients* anyway?

Comment: Can you clarify which Azure SDK packages you're using and help us understand more about your scenario?   Specifically, knowing which Event Hubs client types you are using and how your application is creating and managing those clients would be helpful.

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" Version="5.7.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor" Version="5.7.4" />

Comment: The code inside ProcessClient is          private async Task ProcessEventAsync(ProcessEventArgs arg, string eventSource)
        {  Console.WriteLine(arg); }

Comment: Ok, so you're using the `EventProcessorClient` from the current generation package.  No storage leases are used in load balancing for this version; ownership information is tracked in the metadata for the blob itself.   Maybe you can help us understand more about your end-to-end scenario and what behavior you're seeing that has you concerned?